# configuring awstats with suexec

Tags: suexec, awstats

I have a web server with more than 100 websites running apache and php as fcgid and suexec.

I have configured awstats on my server(FreeBSD) following [awstats installation on FreeBSD](http://www.freebsdmadeeasy.com/tutorials/web-server/analyze-apache-web-server-logs-with-awstats.php)  but when I try to access the statistics of one of the websites I get a "500 Internal Server Error" and in the suexec error logs i get the error "command not in docroot (/usr/local/www/awstats/cgi-bin/awstats.pl)"

I know that the installation works if php is running as an apache module but not as fcgid easily.

Please guide me on how to have awstats configured for all the domains on the server running phpsuexec.

Someone help me.

Thank you

Comment: What `DocumentRoot` do you have set for awstats?

Comment: the websites are under /usr/virtual and awstats is in /usr/local/www/

Answer (score 0):

Run suexec -V, and you will see the *suexec* docroot. Put, copy the awstat installation to this path. For example, in my the path is /var/www :

```
$ suexec -V
 -D AP_DOC_ROOT="/var/www"
 -D AP_GID_MIN=100
 -D AP_HTTPD_USER="apache"
 -D AP_LOG_SYSLOG
 -D AP_SAFE_PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"
 -D AP_UID_MIN=500
 -D AP_USERDIR_SUFFIX="public_html"
```